# Database Design question best way to solve this issue

Tags: sql, database

I'm kind of new in database design and I'm trying to find the best way to solve an issue I'm facing.

Let's think about the following example:

Imagine I want to store information about patients and these patients can have 0+ diseases.

What's the best way of storing arranging the tables to display the diseases that each patient can have? I get confused as to what happens when a patient would have 3 diseases; how is this stored in a relational database? e.g. without having repeated rows on the diseases table for example (static number of diseases)..

I'm not sure if I'm making myself totally clear here!

But let's say I don't think it's efficient to have:

Patient table -
Patient_id , disease_id
`1, (3,4,5,6)`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint:  Look up "association table"/"junction table".

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff Yes - I know about this. But assuming I have a fixed number of diseases; how can I show that a patient has more than 1 disease..

Comment: Using `JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`

Comment: Don't store serialized datas, that is a pain to query, update, delete and you lose the ability to use indexes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you would use an associative entity for that.
Let say you have the following diseases:

```
| Disease_id | Disease_name |
-----------------------------
| 1          | Cancer       |
-----------------------------
| 2          | Leucemia     |
-----------------------------
```

Your patients may look like this

```
| Patient_id | Patient_name |
-----------------------------
| 1          | Peter Jones  |
-----------------------------
| 2          | Mark Jacobs  |
-----------------------------
```

You now create a table like so (lets call it ill_patients)

```
| Patient_id | Disease_id |
---------------------------
| 1          | 1          |
---------------------------
| 1          | 2          |
---------------------------
```

This would mean that poor Peter Jones has cancer as well as leucemia. You can now query your patient table like so:

```
SELECT patients.patient_name, diseases.disease_name
FROM (diseases INNER JOIN ill_patients ON diseases.disease_id = ill_patients.disease_id) INNER JOIN patients ON ill_patients.patient_id = patients.patient_id;
```

This gives you all the patients with their respective diseaes.

Comment: I was missing the 3rd table :P Makes so much more sense now! Thanks

Comment: Missing one join, between the relation table and the disease one

Comment: @Cid yes correct, I am going to edit it once I get home. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2):

Patients:

```
patient_id, name, phone
```

Disease:

```
disease_id, name, description
```

Patient_Disease:

```
patient_id, disease_id
```

Example:

```
patient_id, name  , phone
    1     , 'jhon', '555-1234'

disease_id, name      , description
   1      , 'Cancer'  , 'Cancer is the uncontrolled development of cells.'
   2      , 'Diabetes', 'Diabetes is a disease that occurs when your blood glucose is too high.'

patient_id, disease_id
   1      ,    1
   1      ,    2
```

Then you can do

```
SELECT p.name, d.name, d.description
FROM patients p 
JOIN patient_disease pd
  ON p.patient_id = pd.patient_id
JOIN diseases d
  ON pd.disease_id = d.disease_id
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!